# How to copy all files from a directory to a remote directory using scp?

Tags: scp

My goal is copy only **all files** from **~/local_dir** to **user@host.com /var/www/html/target_dir** using **scp** and do not create local_dir category in local_dir.

```
/var/www/html/target_dir/files..
```

but not

`/var/www/html/target_dir/local_dir/files..` when use -r parameter

Comment: Does `scp * user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir` not do what you want? If so, please [edit] with more detail of what you're trying to do & have tried so far.

Comment: Appending /. is no longer work.
[More here](https://superuser.com/a/1403506/682279)

Comment: In the first paragraph the last word should presumably be target_dir ?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

scp has the -r argument. So, try using:

```
$ scp -r ~/local_dir user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir
```

The -r argument works just like the -r arg in cp, it will transfer your entire folder and all the files and subdirectories inside.

Comment: Your command created `local_dir` directory in /var/www/html/target_dir my goal is copy only files.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. Then just repeat the command, but like this:
`$ scp -r ~/local_dir user@host.com:/var/www/html/`
Then rename new directory if needed.

Comment: Or `$ scp -r ~/local_dir/* user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir` Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Change the wildcard `*` to a dot `.` and you'll copy the directory contents (including any dot files) without copying the directory itself. `scp -pr ~/local_dir/. user@example.com:/path/to/target_dir`

Comment: Another alternate format is `pushd local_dir; scp -r . user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir; popd`  bash provides many ways to say much the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `.` has been broken by a poorly implemented `scp` "bugfix" (see <https://superuser.com/questions/1403473/scp-error-unexpected-filename/1403506#1403506>). `rsync` would be a working alternative.

Answer (score 67):

If your goal is to transfer all files from `local_dir` the `*` wildcard does the trick:

```
$ scp ~/local_dir/* user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir
```

The `-r` option means "recursively", so you must write it when you're trying to transfer an entire directory or several directories.

From `man scp`:

```
-r 
Recursively copy entire directories. Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.
```

So if you have sub-directories inside `local_dir`, the last example will only transfer files, but if you set the `-r` option, it will transfer files and directories.

Comment: 1+ Because you need to read the comments in the accepted answer to get to the correct answer, while this one just explains it directly.

Comment: Directories aren't copied: `not a regular file`.

Comment: i don't recomand using "*" because it won't copy hidden files and directories

Answer (score 32):

Appending `/.` to your source directory will transfer its contents instead of the directory itself. In contrast to the wildcard solution, this will include any hidden files too.

```
$ scp -r ~/local_dir/. user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir
```

Credit for this solution goes to roaima, but I thought it should be posted as an actual answer, not only a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has been broken by a poorly implemented `scp` "bugfix" (see <https://superuser.com/questions/1403473/scp-error-unexpected-filename/1403506#1403506>).

Answer (score 18):

Follow these steps:

1. Copy directory `local_dir` with all its sub-directories:

   ```
   scp -r ~/local_dir user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir
   ```
2. copy only the contents of `local_dir` and not the directory `local_dir` itself:

   ```
   scp -r ~/local_dir/* user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir
   ```
3. Do not use: `scp -r ~/local_dir/. user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir` as it throws an error(just tested and received the following error):

   ```
   scp: error: unexpected filename: .
   ```

Comment: I also get the error of unexpected filename . However, using the wildcard does not work either cause the directory has so many files that is exceeds the character limit for commands when the wildcard gets expanded. macOS

Comment: @RichardKiefer : You can use wildcards like ? with * to further isolate the search results and then pass it to scp. Try this link, it may help:

[Wildcards](https://www.tecmint.com/use-wildcards-to-match-filenames-in-linux/)

Comment: Thanks Syed, but my point was that I actually want to target all elements in the folder, and not filter any. And if my directory has too many, than the wildcard will just not work.

Comment: @RichardKiefer: My apologies Richard, to get all the files copied we can use a small bash script. Use: `ls -l | awk '{print $9}'` and redirect all the output (which would be all the file names) to a txt file. Read the txt file, one line at a time and use that input with scp to copy the files:

`input=/home/user/filename.txt
while IFS= read -r line`

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
rsync -avP ~/local_dir/ user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir/
```

should work.

And you can run it with `-n` at its end

```
rsync -avP ~/local_dir/ user@host.com:/var/www/html/target_dir -n
```

so that it simulates the operation and you can check that the result is what you wish for.

Comment: You would need to add a trailing `/` to `~/local_dir` (i.e. `rsync -avP ~/local_dir/ etc.`) to prevent the creation of `/var/www/html/target_dir/local_dir` on the destination side, which is one key requirement of the OP.